# In App Purchasing with IBAction/Button

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase, ibaction

I have a pretty interesting question. It seems like it should be easy to solve but perhaps I am just over thinking it?

Brief:
I want to use IBAction Buttons to activate a purchase instead of a Table View.

Detailed:

First off, I am using this tutorial as a guide. (A great tutorial - check it out. Thank you, Ray!)
http://www.raywenderlich.com/21081/introduction-to-in-app-purchases-in-ios-6-tutorial

1. If you scroll down to where it says:

   ```
   - (void)buyButtonTapped:(id)sender {

   UIButton *buyButton = (UIButton *)sender;
   SKProduct *product = _products[buyButton.tag];

   NSLog(@"Buying %@...", product.productIdentifier);
   [[RageIAPHelper sharedInstance] buyProduct:product]; }
   ```

This is where I am getting stuck.  The example uses a table view however I don't want to use one of these in my app. All I want to do is use a IBAction button that I manually created.

So I made this button, and hooked it up and got it working with the NSLog.

```
-(IBAction)buyProductButton:(id)sender {

    NSLog(@"Buy Something.");

}
```

So my question is what do I put in this IBAction instead of

```
- (void)buyButtonTapped:(id)sender {

    UIButton *buyButton = (UIButton *)sender;
    SKProduct *product = _products[buyButton.tag];

    NSLog(@"Buying %@...", product.productIdentifier);
    [[RageIAPHelper sharedInstance] buyProduct:product]; }
```

in order to get the button to activate the purchase?

Maybe something like this?

```
-(IBAction)buyProductButton:(id)sender {

    SKProduct *product = _products;

    NSLog(@"Buying %@...", product.productIdentifier);
    [[RageIAPHelper sharedInstance] buyProduct:product]; }
```

But yeaaa, it doesn't work.

Any ideas would be greatly & massively appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you are not setting up the correct product:

```
SKProduct *product = _products[buyButton.tag];

NSLog(@"Buying %@...", product.productIdentifier);
[[RageIAPHelper sharedInstance] buyProduct:product];
```

try using your product tag, where buyButton.tag

Comment: Since I am not using the table view that incorporates the "byButton.tag" i just want to manually buy a product. So how do I purchase a product with this if it's in a IBAction button?

Comment: Do I put in my com.companyname.appname.iapname instead of buyButton.tag? I guess I'm not understanding. Sorry.

Comment: I do, ya. I've set all that up correctly.  I just don't know how the code would look with the identifier in there? SKProduct *product = _products[com.companyname.appname.productname];

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that I have tried and it worked. I have used a button to make a particular purchase using the codes below.

create the variable Array _products in @interface of M file:

```
@interface .... (){

    NSArray *_products;

}
```

Put this to your viewDidLoad method:

```
[[RageIAPHelper sharedInstance] requestProductsWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSArray *products) {

        if (success) {

            _products = products;

        }
    }];
```

The above code will fill the "_products" with the product(s) u have registered at store. 
and in the button function use the below code to buy the product.

```
SKProduct *product = _products[0];    
[[RageIAPHelper sharedInstance] buyProduct:product];
```

I have used "0" in "_products[0]" to refer to the store product.. if you have many products you can use the corresponding number in [] of the _products[] to buy that particular item.